# iAd runs well on simulator but not on device

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

When I run my application I can see my iAd in the simulator, that is pre-filled with "Test Advertisement"

However, when I run the application on my device, the iAd area is blank, with no pre-filled ad.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer may be in apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW14).  Basically you have to be set up properly for it and it will sometimes send errors on purpose.  In addition, you may have to wait a few seconds for an ad to come up.

If you think things are in order, you can try Adding a NSLog() to the following delegate functions inside of the [AdBannerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) protocol:

```
bannerViewDidLoadAd:
```

and

```
bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:
```

Make sure that you are set up to receive those delegate actions from the iAd banner view that isn't working.